# how to fetch the data from request body in anguar2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular4-forms

i have created one URL and given to the end-user so when user hit my URL  from other module i want to fetch the the data from the request body and and after fetching the data i am passing these data to my service and then validating and getting the response from my service.
but when user click on my URL and passing the data in URL then
I am able to fetch the data from URL like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    .subscribe((params : Params) => {
        this.email=params['id'];
    });
```

but I am not able to fetch the data from request body when the user hit my URL so that i can fetch the data from the body and pass it to my  service.

I need to fetch the two parameters from the request body.

Answer (score 0):

Please first understand that the code you show is **not** a request to an api so there is no body.

All you are doing here is looking at the current route that shows in the address bar (ie. the current page of your angular app). There is no request body to fetch data from, only the query string params you can see in the address bar.

In other words, `this.route` refers to the CURRENT route of your angular app showing in the browser.

If you want to call an API and get data then you need to create a service to do that. For example:

@Injectable()
export class StoriesService {

```
constructor(private http:Http,private constService :ConstantsService) { }

public getStories()
{
    this.http
        .get(this.constService.apiBaseUrl + "/Stories")
        .subscribe ((data: Response) => console.log(data));
}
```

}

In this example `data` is the request body returned by the call to `[apiBaseUrl]/stories`.

I would advise reading [this tutorial](http://www.gistia.com/talk-backend-services-angular-2s-http-client/).